# How to create an Integration environment in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, git, magento2.4, magento-cloud

I have the **Production** and **Staging** environments in my Magento Cloud, but I don't see any Integration environment.

Checking this link I see that it's supposed to exits.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/architecture/pro-develop-deploy-workflow.html

[image: Magento 2.4 Cloud Integration environment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run these commands to have your integration environment as a child of the **Staging** branch.

```
git checkout staging -f
git checkout -b integration
magento-cloud environment:info -e integration parent staging
magento-cloud environment:activate integration
```

[image: Magento Cloud Integration environment]

Comment: When I ran the `magento-cloud environment:info -e integration parent staging` it shows  error `[InvalidArgumentException]                    
  Specified environment not found: integration`. Any Idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: @MilanChandro change the name integration to the name of your environment. In my example, my environment was called integration.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1** :- Checkout to Staging Branch

```
git checkout staging
```

**Step 2** :- Create a Integration Brach

```
git checkout -b integration
```

**Step 3** :-

```
git add . && git commit -m "Integration Environment Testing" && git push origin integration
```

**Step 4** :- Create Integration under Staging Environment

```
magento-cloud environment:info -e integration parent staging
```

**Step 5** :- Activate Integration Environment

```
magento-cloud environment:activate integration

magento-cloud environment:list
```

**Step 6** :- **After Integration Activation** - Migrate your Staging Database in your Integration Environment. For more information follow this link :- https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/live/stage-prod-migrate.html#cloud-live-migrate-db

**Step 7** :- **Sync Your Media Files** from Staging to Integration. First Login to Staging SSH  & Run

```
rsync -azvP pub/media/ <destination_environment_ssh_link@ssh.region.magento.cloud>:pub/media/
```

Once Completed, **Do an Git Push to Start Deploy Once more** & Integration will be working.

**Screenshot**

**Git Branch**

[image]

**After your Integration Environment has been Activated**

[image]

**From Magento Cloud WebUI - Check the Log for Success**

[image]

Comment: Note: If the `git push origin integration` not works, Run the `git push magento integration`. Here `magento` is the replacement for `origin` text. To check, run the `git remote -v` to check the remote branch info.